# ROR: Zero-padding removed upon database query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there anyway to make .find not remove zeropadding on the values it pulls back from the database?

ie. I have zipcodes in a database and some of them are shorter than 5 characters. I am zeropadding thme back to 5 characters in the database, so I end up with "00210" for example. However, this value just becomes "210" in my array.

I know I can use "%05d" % value to zeropad it when it's going back into the views... but I'd rather not have to zeropad it on the way out like that.

Comment: Looks like the problem is inside your database. Check type of zipcode field

Comment: Is your zip code field of type string or int?  I would wager AR would not change a string it pulled back from the db, but it might remove leading zeros on integers.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't strip the leading zeros as a text or char type.

Still... it seems like you should be able to return an integer with leading zeros as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Fixnum` (the Ruby type you're dealing with) only cares about value. `my_var = 00000001` in ruby sets `my_var` to 1, and outputting it as a string results in `"1"`. If you want to format it differently, you'll have to rely on string functionality.